# Discord - After joining a voice channel muted (from another server), the 'voiceStateUpdate' event doesn't emit on unmute/mute. Why?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm currently coding a discord.js Discord bot. If I mute myself on guild1 and join into a voice channel on guild2, the `voiceStateUpdate` event emits because of the join, that's normal. And also I'm muted, which is completely correct. But if I now unmute myself, a second `voiceStateUpdate` event should be emitted, but isn't. Why is that?

I've already searched for a solution/reason on the github project of discord.js but I didn't find anything.

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate',(oldm,newm) => {
    console.log(oldm,newm);
});
```

Is it possible, that this is an error of the Discord API?

Comment: Is the bot in both servers? Also, just making sure, this is the process which is producing the result? **1.** Join voice channel in Guild A. (event emitted) **2.** Mute yourself. (event emitted) **3.** Join voice channel in Guild B. (event emitted) **4.** Unmute yourself. (event *not* emitted)

Comment: @slothiful No, the bot isn't in both servers. It is only in the second on. But the process you described was accurate. The problem is, that users, who are coming from voice channels of foreign servers and connect muted to a voice channel of my server, aren't tracked if they unmute themselves.

Comment: I can't reproduce the result. Joining a voice channel in the bot's server while muted emits the event, and unmuting myself emits it again. What version of Discord.js are you using?